# Drawing causal relationship from an observational study?

Tags: statistics, definition, statistical-inference

I am reading OpenIntro's Statistics and came across this problem:

[image]

In part b) I don't believe one can establish causal relationships because the research is an observational study (I think).

After reading through the study itself,

[image]
it seems that its authors do draw a causal relationship.

Any help explaining as to why this is would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think it has to do with the part that claims: "This induction primes ... to identify others' emotions." I disagree that a causal relationship can be established in this way, but you did not ask my opinion on that. However, I do feel this is why the organizers _imagine_ they can show causation from studies like this.